# Why does the file manager show all of my Windows partitions except one?

Tags: windows, live-cd, partitioning, filemanager, livedvd

From Disk Management in Windows 10, you can see that I have 5 partitions on my computer that are either NTFS or FAT32.

[image]

When I boot up the computer using an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live CD and then open the file manager, I can see the following partitions listed at the bottom of the left pane:

- Windows
- SYSTEM
- MX200_DISK1
- HP_TOOLS

However, it does not show the HP_RECOVERY partition.  I am curious as to why it isn't showing the HP_RECOVERY partition but it does show all of the other partitions.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot from Ubuntu's live disk?

Comment: Why would you want to see that partition?  It is protected so that if something happens to the system, i.e. a virus, it will remain intact so that you can recover your system with it.

Comment: Recovery images Ubuntu wouldn't recognize only a special program to reinstall Windows

Comment: @Terrance I didn't know it's protected.  Out of curiosity's sake, is that something that can be set and unset in Windows?  I don't see any mechanism to do that in the WIndows Disk Management.

Comment: If you run `gparted` as sudo, you can right click the partition in gparted and choose `Manage Flags` and you will probably see that `Hidden` is selected.  Linux should honor this permission and not show you the partition, however, sudo can override this permission and you might mess up any chance of recovery, unless you created the recovery set from Windows.  Once you have that set the recovery partition can be recreated if it gets destroyed.

Comment: Also, take a look here for unhiding from Windows:  http://defaultreasoning.com/2009/05/29/unhide-the-recovery-partition-on-a-basic-disk-with-diskpart/

Comment: @Terrance I ran `sudo gparted`, looked at `Manage flags` on the HP_RECOVERY partition, and `hidden` is not checked.  Also I ran `diskpart` in Windows per your link and it said the type of that partition is 07 which means it's not hidden.

Comment: My guess would then be they have probably changed it to BIOS / UEFI control or some sort of firmware on the drive.  I would suggest calling HP support, but the last time I called them they were worthless with information.